# boost date/time

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I have the following code but get the locale error when I try to compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/parsers.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string ds("2011-01-02");
  date dt(from_string(ds));

  date_facet *f=new date_facet("%Y-%m-%d");
  std::locale loc=std::locale(std::locale("en_US"),f);
  std::cout.imbue(loc);

  time_facet *facet = new time_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
  std::cout<<second_clock::local_time()<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is the error message:

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:18:1: error: ‘locale’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:18:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘loc’
```

after the edits, the error is:

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:18:1: error: ‘locale’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Do you need to / did you try `#include <boost/locale.hpp>`?

Comment: if I add that, this is what I get: fatal error: boost/locale.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: What version of boost are you using? It's only in 1.46+ it seems. http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/index.html

Comment: @jeffamaphone, what version of boost has `locale.hpp` located at the root level? More specifically, what version has a locale implementation? It's not in 1.47, and I don't recall one in earlier versions.

Comment: @jeffamaphone, I see, it isn't part of the standard distribution.

Comment: I believe it is 1.38, the standard version in ubuntu

Comment: Are you expecting to use it, or are you expecting `std::locale`?  If so you should `#include <locale>` and maybe say `std::`?

Comment: I edited my program with the fixes but it didn't work..

Comment: @jeffamaphone, I changed the code to std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(),f)); and I get this error: In function`unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const&)':

Comment: test.cpp:.text._ZN5boost9date_time19month_str_to_ushortINS_9gregorian10greg_monthEEEtRKSs[unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x97):undefinedreferenceto `boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status......I am obviously missing a library, but which one?

Answer (score 1):

Your missing `std::` in front of `locale`.  Specifically,

```
locale loc=locale(locale("en_US"),f);
```

should become

```
std::locale loc=std::locale(std::locale("en_US"),f);
```

And you need to `#include <locale>`.

Comment: I did, and now the error is:error: ‘locale’ was not declared in this scope
I'll edit my program with the changes.

Comment: @itcplpl, sorry I missed one of them. The innermost `locale` was missing the `std::`.  I've edited it.

Comment: @itcplpl, I honestly don't know. Have you tried cleaning the build directory of any and all intermediate files? It may help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Boost.DateTime has a binary component that is only needed if you're using its to_string/from_string
```

from the [getting started guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries)

You should build it first, [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) should help